# Deducing the width of the div, from the width another div - How could I do this?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have two divs inside a `div` as shown below:

```css
.w-35 {
  width: 35%;
}

.d-flex {
  display: flex!important;
}

.mr-auto {
  margin-right: auto!important;
}

.flex-column {
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical!important;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal!important;
  -ms-flex-direction: column!important;
  flex-direction: column!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="mr-auto">
    <div>Box1</div>
  </div>

  <div class="w-35">
    <div class="flex-column"> Box2 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

While the second `div` has a width of `35%`, is there a way I could correctly deduce the width of the first `div` with class `mr-auto` to be 65%? I always want the width of the first `div` to be `100% - width_of_second_div_in_percent`.

How could I do this?

Comment: Why would you want to calculate the percentage remaining if you already have a fixed percentage? Why not to add a fixed 65% in the first div?

Comment: @JoseA.Ayllón If I change `35%` to `45%` or even `25%` , the first div must adjust automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just set `flex: 1` on `.mr-auto` element then it will take rest of the free width in that row and you do not need to set fixed with. Also instead of `width` you could use `flex` property on the element with fixed width.

With this approach width of the `.mr-auto` element will always depend on the width of the fixed element.

```css
.w-35 {
  flex: 0 0 35%;
}

.mr-auto {
  flex: 1;
}

.d-flex {
  display: flex;
}

.d-flex > div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="mr-auto">
    <div>....</div>
  </div>

  <div class="w-35">
    <div class="flex-column"> ... </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you help differentiate between `flex: 1` and `margin-right: auto!important` ?

Comment: Inside flex container, margin-right: auto will position flex-child on the left start of the empty space, and `flex` is used for defining flex properties like basis, grow and shrink.